# SharePoint 2013 - Discussion Board view only shows one record

Tags: 2013, view

I should add that setting the Item Limit value works, no matter what that value is. However, clicking the link to show the **next** page/group of records only shows one record. This is the case if we choose the next group and will keep doing this but still only showing one record.

I can set Item Limits in other views for this list, but this particular view is having a problem. I have temporarily bumped up the Item Limit to a large number to avoid this from happening.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated - thanks